# retrieve lib version generated with autotool

Tags: c, linux, gcc, autotools, libtool

I'm trying to find a way to get the version of my [c](/questions/tagged/c) library, compiled with [libtool](/questions/tagged/libtool).

I added `-version-info 1:1:1` to `LD_FLAGS` in `makefile.am` and the output is ok: `lib.so.0.1.1`

What I need is to retrieve runtime the version of that library and show it on an information panel.

I'm thinking on two different ways to do that:

1. Use an external file (eg. header) where I can define versions and that make makefile.am able to read version values from it. In this way I can access it form my code also.
2. A way, different then parsing the filename of library on FS, to retrieve the version set by `-version-info` option.

Is one of those ideas applicable?

Comment: i've seen many projects using option #1

Comment: @EmilCondrea me too, but not with autotool. Could you show how to do that with libtool?

Comment: also have you considered passing the version in CFLAGS: -DVERSION=0:1:1?(for being able to read it from code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `LIB_VERSION = 0:1:1`

Use it: `-version-info $(LIB_VERSION)` and append it to cflags if you want to use it from code: `-DVERSION=$(LIB_VERSION)`

Comment: Thanks. Good Idea, but I'm looking for a solution that leave makefile as is. In other words a solution that does not imply to modify makefile each time a new release is released.

Comment: Basically adding a AC_DEFINE([LIB_VERSION], 0:1:1) in configure.ac generates a define in config.h and with this value and you can use it from code.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the makefile manually maybe you can use a script which sets an environment variable(which will be used for generating the constants and -version-info values) or modifies automatically the configure.ac.